# How to apply svm to a dataset with a numerical (not categorical) dependent variable?

Tags: r, svm, caret

Context: I have some band values from a sentinel - 2 derived .tiff
I now want to make a prediction regarding areas where i have no actual field data
i.e. make a carbon map of sorts

Libraries are:

```
library("e1071")
library("caret")

IndependentVar<-AGCplot[,3:19]
DependentVar<-AGCplot[,2]
mod_svm <- svm(AGC~B2+B3+B4+B5+B6+B7+B8+B8A+B11+B12+NDVI+IRECI+VV+HV+NDWI+MMRI+MASI, data=AGCplot)
summary(mod_svm)
pred <- predict(mod_svm,IndependentVar)
```

I can't run a confusion matrix as ways of evaluating the model because the dependent variable is numerical.
What can i run to valuate how my model did?

Comment: It sounds like you want to solve a regression problem and not a classification problem.

Comment: Yes exactly @MotiN. I'm rather new to the subject. Do you have any references regarding regression that apply to my issue. If this is not really the platform could you give me a reference for one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See here for a simple tutorial on SVR - https://towardsdatascience.com/an-introduction-to-support-vector-regression-svr-a3ebc1672c2

Comment: @MotiN Thank you